# Memory consumption of a script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, memory, virtual-memory

Is there way to check the memory (physical & virtual) consumption of a script, of course in the moment of its execution.

Calculating the used memory minus the used memory before and after the execution is not a good solution I think.

Comment: Kind of old but I found [this](https://gist.github.com/netj/526585) online which is a bash script checks the `RSS` of the spawned process group at regular intervals. It might provide you with a good starting off point on writing your own script.

Answer (score 2):

```
/usr/bin/time -v /your/script.sh
```

Comment: You should mention that this is GNU only.